# complements of a powerset

Tags: logic

I have a function

$Q(n)=p(\{1,\ldots,n\})\setminus\{\{\}\}$ such that it won't have the empty set in it.

Note, if you are going to change out my equations for Latex, I would greatly appreciate it if in doing so, you didn't change the meaning of the statements.

How can I express $Q(n+1)$ solely in terms of of $Q(n)$?

Basically

$$Q(n+1)=Q(n)+ A  \text{ where } A =(Q(n+1)\setminus Q(n))$$

i.e., $A$ is the set of elements ONLY in $Q(n+1)$ but not in $Q(n)$.

I don't even need a solution as much as where do I go from here. This is part of a large proof and I am stuck at this part.

Comment: Consider using the term "proper subset" meaning "a subset that is not equal to its superset and is not empty" together with the set $\{Q(n)\}$.

Comment: Where you write $p(1,\ldots,n)$, do you mean $P\{1,\ldots,n\}$, where $P$ means powerset?  In standard notation $(1,\ldots,n)$ is a tuple and $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is a set.  It's easier to make sure you're understood if you use standard notation.

Comment: I believe someone edited some of my equations.

Comment: It was supposed to be P({1,....n}) but when someone added latex they actually changed the way it looked.

Comment: @ChrisJones : It's not really LaTeX; it's MathJax.  LaTeX is an immensely more sophisticated language.  LaTeX doesn't function only in math mode.  A LaTeX document might have several style files specifying page layout plus the main file in which the actual document is typed.  It keeps track of the numbering of sections and chapters and other things$\ldots\ldots\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Without more details, it is difficult to say what sort of operations you are allowed to use. Here is one possible way of doing this by using unions:

$Q(n + 1) = Q(n) \cup \{X \cup \{n + 1\} : X \in Q(n)\} \cup \{\{n + 1\}\}$

Comment: It looks like you defined a set having two-element sets as elements along with other elements from the original set...  Or if I read the set notation incorrectly, then it looks like $Q(n+1)=Q(n)\cup\{n+1\}$...

Comment: @abiessu It should mean: $Q(n + 1)$ (the non empty subsets of $\{1, ..., n + 1\}$) consist of the nonempty subsets of $\{1, ..., n\}$ (i.e. $Q(n)$), all sets containing $n + 1$ and some element of $\{1, ..., n\}$ (i.e the second part of the union), and finally the singleton $\{n + 1\}$ (the last part).

Comment: I see it now, it looks right.  :-)